# Simple MYSQL Query Not Returning Results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a simple select statement using PHP and I'm certain there should be results but I am not receiving any data when I run the page.

```
$username = 'racarric';
$username_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

if (mysql_num_rows($username_check) > 0) {
    echo "Username is already in use";
    //break;
}
else {
    echo "No users have this username";
}
```

In my database I have a record where username is 'racarric'.

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_` function 2nd you have not executed your query. It is just a string look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and know more about how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many problems here. Here are the big ones.

**First**, and this is the (main) reason you don't get results, you're not actually executing the query. You store a string version of the query that you want to run, but you never execute it with, for example, [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You would need something like this:

```
// ...
$username_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$query = mysql_query($username_check); // this is the new line

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) { // note the parameter change
// ...
```

**Second**, you're using the `mysql` library. As explained in the big red box in [the documentation link above](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), you [shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1). The `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure - they have been removed entirely from modern versions of PHP (version 7.0 and higher). Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

**Third**, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of the SQL Injection part and wasn't too worried about that for now. It's a pretty simple school homework assignment. What's odd is I took a course at my college last semester that taught MYSQL/PHP using the mysql_* functions, I'm shocked they didn't tell us that it was no longer supported. Thanks for the reply. I should be able to get it from here. EDIT: After looking at some old files we were taught using mysqli. I must have forgot and used too old of resources to help with this assignment.

Comment: @Andrew_114 I'm glad that helped. Please remember to select the checkmark next to the answer! Also, it's pretty inexcusable that they taught you to use `mysql_*`. Those functions have been deprecated for 4 years and were removed entirely in 7.0, which went to general availability almost 2 years ago. You might want to flag this for your instructor.

Comment: @Andrew_114 Ah, okay. That's better! It's very easy to type `mysql_...` by mistake and leave out the `i`. If you have control over the machine, it's better just to disable the `mysql` extension. That way, code using the old functions won't even run, forcing you to be consistent in using `mysqli_...` or PDO.